# Determining the period of $ \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(3x)}$

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I would like to compute the period of this function which is a fraction of two trigonometric functions. $$ \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(3x)}$$

Is there a theorem for this? what trick to use to easily find the period?
I started by reducing the fraction but I'm stuck on the rest.

For example, let $T$ be the period to be calculated: $$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(3x)}  =\frac{\sin(2x + 2 T)}{\cos(3x+3T)} =  \frac{\sin(2x) \cos(2T)+\sin(2T) \cos(2x)}{\cos(3x) \cos(3T)-\sin(3T)\sin(3x)}$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know the periods of the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: Yes, for $\sin(2x)$ is $\pi$ and for the $\cos(3x)$ is $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$

Comment: and I know about the LCM rule, but I think it work only for sum and difference

Comment: I suggest that you state that you know the periods of $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ and that you are familiar with the LCM rule, but that you are not sure it applies to the quotient of trigonometric functions in the question itself so that readers of your question understand the precise source of your doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the period is $p$, and suppose the domain of the function is suitably defined, then for all values of $x$ in the domain, we must have $$\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 3x}=\frac{\sin(2(x+p))}{\cos(3(x+p))}$$
$$\implies \sin 2x\cos(3x+3p)=\cos 3x\sin(2x+2p)$$

If we set $x=0$, we have $$\sin(2p)=0\implies 2p=k\pi.k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

On the other hand, noting that $\sin 2x=\cos 3x$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{10}$, amongst other possible values, if we set $x=\frac{\pi}{10}$, we get $$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}+3p\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}+2p\right)=\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}-2p\right)$$
$$\implies\frac{3\pi}{10}+3p=\pm\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}-2p\right)+n\cdot2\pi,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

From this we get $p=n\cdot2\pi$ or $p=\frac{3\pi}{5}+n\cdot2\pi$

In order to satisfy this and the previous result for $p$ we have to choose $k$ and $n$ such that both equations $p=\frac{k\pi}{2}$ and $p=n\cdot2\pi$ are satisfied and $p$ has minimum value, so we choose $k=4$ and $n=1$.

Therefore the period is $2\pi$.

Comment: Is there another way to do this ? rather than to notice that sin (2x) = cos (3x) when x = $\pi/10$ ? it's complicated to notice that I find.

Comment: I chose that so that there would be a simple equation in $p$ to solve. Theoretically you could choose any value for $x$ and find an equation for $p$, but such an equation may be difficult to solve. I would say that it's the standard method: find $p$ so that $f(x)=f(x+p)\forall x$

Answer (score 2):

If F(x) has a period T
Then F(ax+b) has a period |(T/a)|
If the expression is separated by + or - signs take the LCM of periods
One of important concepts for determining period of function involving multiple periodic terms is that individual function should repeat simultaneously. This gives rises to LCM rule. It is defined for terms which appear as sum or difference in the function. However, LCM concept can be extended to division or multiplication of periodic terms as well.

Exceptions to LCM rule are important. Even function and function comprising of cofunctions are two notable exceptions to LCM rule. Besides, LCM of irrational periods of different kinds is not possible. This fact is used to determine periodic nature of function involving irrational periods. If LCM can not be determined, then given function is not periodic in the first place.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thanks. But what about the fraction ? the period of the numerator is $\pi$ and the period of the denominator is $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$, if i take the LCM I get $2 \pi$ and this the correct response according the my software, but I think it just works by chance

Comment: It's a lot of information, but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(3x)}=\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{4\cos^3(x)-3\cos x}=\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}$$
$\sin x$ and $\cos x$ has a period of $2\pi$. Therefore $\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}$ has a period of $2\pi$.
The fundamental period must be $2\pi/n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have
$$\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}=\frac{2\sin(x+2\pi/n)}{4\cos^2(x+2\pi/n)-3}$$
Substituting $x=\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}$ we get$$\frac{2\sin(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n})}{4\cos^2(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n})-3}=\frac{2\sin(\pi)}{4\cos^2(\pi)-3}=0$$
$$\implies \sin\bigg(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\bigg)=0$$
This is true only if $n=1$ or $2$. If $n=2$ then
$$\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}=\frac{2\sin(x+\pi)}{4\cos^2(x+\pi)-3}=-\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}$$
Therefore $n\ne2$. So the fundamental period is $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it correct to say that if we have two functions with the same period then :  the fraction (if defined), the product, the sum and the difference or any combinaison of these functions, it's with the same period.  ?   I understand the first two lines but why did you add the other lines ?

Comment: Ok I see.  But what do you recommend to find the periods? for each case, a way of doing things?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\tan x\cdot\cos x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$. Period of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $2\pi$ while the period of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is $\pi$. Is it clear now?

Comment: I edited my comments, you're right